# Scala: require that a function argument is a member of some class?

Tags: scala, methods

I want to do something like

```
class A {
  def f1: Unit = ...
  def f2: Unit = ...
}
def foo(f: => Unit) {
  (new A).f // ???
}
```

where f is supposed to be a member function of class A. I believe the standard solution is

```
def foo(f: A => Unit) {
  f(new A)
}
```

and use it in this way

```
foo(_.f1)
foo(_.f2)
```

But now I can pass in an arbitrary function that has this signature, which may be not desired. Is there anyway to ensure that, the function I pass in is a member of certain class?

Comment: Maybe you can just pass A and then call it as `theAInstance.f`?

Comment: You could try using reflection.

Comment: @om-nom-nom I modified the question a little bit to better clarify. Notice that I have multiple member methods of `A` that satisfy this signature (both `f1` and `f2`), and the whole point is to let the user choose which one to use.

Comment: @Ptharien'sFlame Yes, that's definitely one solution, and I believe it is the only one if we are writing java or something else. But since in scala we can do `foo(a: {def f1: Unit})` (which is achieved via reflection in java, if existing classes are not allowed to be modified!), I am just wondering whether the "inverse" is also possible.

Comment: @Kane I don't think so, since, unlike Objective-C, Scala has no `SEL` type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you don't mind a few contortions, you can use the fact that a function IS a class after all...

```
// abstract class MyIntToString extends (Int => String) // declare here if you want 
                                                       // to use from different classes

// EDIT: f1 and f2 are now val instead of def as per comment below
// by @Régis Jean-Gilles
class A {
    abstract class MyIntToString private[A]() extends (Int => String) 
           // if MyIntToString is declared here
           // with a constructor private to the enclosing class
           // you can ensure it's used only within A (credit goes to @AlexeyRomanov 
           // for his comment below)
    val f1 = new MyIntToString {
        def apply(i: Int) = i.toString + " f1"
    }
    val f2= new MyIntToString {
        def apply(i: Int) = i.toString + " f2"
    }
 }

def foo(f: A#MyIntToString) = f(42) // f: MyIntToString if MyIntToString not nested in A
val a = A
```

now you can do:

```
scala> foo((new A).f1)
res1: String = 42 f1

scala> foo((new A).f2)
res2: String = 42 f2
```

but foo will not accept `Int => String` signatures

```
scala> val itos = (i:Int) => i.toString
itos: Int => String = <function1>

scala> foo(itos)
<console>:11: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int => String
 required: MyIntToString
              foo(itos)
                  ^
```

Comment: To prevent users from creating "wrong" instances of `MyIntToString`, it could have a private primary constructor.

Comment: You definitly don't want to reinstanciate the functions on each call for nothing, so turning f1 and f2 into vals would be a good idea.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov sorry if I misunderstand what you're saying, but I'm not instantiating `MyIntToString` I'm subclassing it (well, I'm subclassing it AND instantiating its anonymous subclass). MyIntToString could be made `sealed` and saved in the same file as `A`, if the intent is to restrict its use to class A

Comment: @PaoloFalabella Well, instances of the anonymous subclass are instances of `MyIntToString` as well. Yes, making it `sealed` would work as well.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov you're right,I'm sorry. I forgot you can't subclass a class with only private constructors.