# Function type of all methods of a single class - in Scala

Tags: function, scala, methods

Not sure how to properly formulate this (hence, how to look it up), but here goes:

I understand how a method applied to an object can become a function object. For example:

```
case class User(name: String, age: Int)
val user = User("", 0)
user.name _   // () => String
```

So, if I had a method  `def meth(f: () => String)`, I could do: `meth(user.name _)`

Is is possible to define a **type** that has as instances the **methods of class** `User` ?
(the function objects obtained from these methods, more precisely)

In order words, what would the type of `f` in `def meth(f: ???)` be, in order to be able to do this:  `meth(user.name _)`  and `meth(user.age _)`

Thanks!

Comment: Not quite sure what you're trying to archive but perhaps you could use `user.productIterator` (and accept User as a argument to meth) to go though all the fields and do something with them?

Comment: Since `User` declares `name: String` and `age: Int`, how do you imagine your type to look like? `() => Either[String, Int]`? `() => Any`?

Comment: As @mhs said, it is confusing that the signatures of the two functions are different. Not sure if I catch your point, but are you asking something like this question that I asked before? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13730926/scala-require-that-a-function-argument-is-a-member-of-some-class

Comment: It all started with having to call methods on a potentially-null object(Yes, I know about Option, but I'm the client of this code).So, I was repeatedly doing this: val f1 = if (user == nul )"" else user.getFirstName; //etc . So I ended up with this: def valueOrDefault[T](u: User, f:()=> T, default: T) = if (user == null) default else f() . I call it like this: valueOrDefault(user, user.getFirstName, ""); valueOrDefault(user, user.getAge, 0).Which works, but I was wondering whether it's possible to abstract all methods of u under one function type (rather than f: () => T)(probably not).

Comment: @teo then you probably want something like `def getName(user: User) = Option(user).map(_.name).getOrElse("")` and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the only way to do something like that is to use macro's. I once created a macro that does the following (note that some details changed in the current implementation and thus are empty).

```
case class Metadata(instance: AnyRef, name: String) {

  def value = ??? // use reflection to invoke `name` on `instance`
}

object Metadata extends ((AnyRef, String) => Metadata) {

  implicit def anyToMetadata(sym: Any): Metadata = 
    macro MetadataMacro.anyToMetadataImpl
}

private[staticReflection] object MetadataMacro {

  def anyToMetadataImpl(c: Context)(sym: c.Expr[Any]): c.Expr[Metadata] = {

    import c.universe._

    val metadata = // match the tree and create the appropriate metadata instance

    c.Expr(metadata)
  }
}
```

In code you would then use it like this:

```
case class User(name:String)

def test(metadata:Metadata) {
  println(metadata.name + "->" + metadata.value)
}

val u = User("test")

test(u.name) // name -> test
```

The code as it was valid almost a year ago can be found here: [ee/scala/staticReflection/Metadata.scala](http://code.google.com/p/scala-implicit-metadata-plugin/source/browse/trunk/staticReflection/src/ee/scala/staticReflection/Metadata.scala). More info about [macros as they are now](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/overview.html).

If this is what you were looking for, please let me know so I can see if I can convert the original to a working version.

---

### Edit

I managed to get the old one working. To use it simply copy-past the code into a separate project (I use Eclipse) and then link the projects via the `Java Build Path`. Working version:

```
package ee.scala.staticReflection

import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.Context
import language.implicitConversions

case class Metadata(instance: AnyRef, name: String) {
  // any comments on how to improve this part are welcome
  val runtimeUniverse = scala.reflect.runtime.universe
  val mirror = runtimeUniverse.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
  val instanceMirror = mirror.reflect(instance)
  val method = instanceMirror.symbol.selfType.member(runtimeUniverse newTermName name).asMethod
  val methodMirror = instanceMirror.reflectMethod(method)

  def value = methodMirror()
}

object Metadata extends ((AnyRef, String) => Metadata) {

  implicit def anyToMetadata(sym: Any): Metadata = macro MetadataMacro.anyToMetadataImpl
}

private[staticReflection] object MetadataMacro {

  def anyToMetadataImpl(c: Context)(sym: c.Expr[Any]): c.Expr[Metadata] = {
    import c.universe._

    def createMetadataInstance(select: Select): Tree =
      treeBuild.mkMethodCall(
        c.mirror.staticModule("ee.scala.staticReflection.Metadata"),
        newTermName("apply"),
        List(select.qualifier, Literal(Constant(select.name.toString))))

    val metadata = sym.tree match {
      //normal select
      case select: Select => createMetadataInstance(select)

      //could be a call using a right associative operator
      case Ident(name) =>
        c.enclosingMethod.collect {
          case ValDef(_, refName, _, select: Select) if refName == name => createMetadataInstance(select)
        }
          .headOption
          .getOrElse(throw new Exception("Could not find ValDef for " + name))

      case _ => throw new Exception("Could not create metadata")
    }

    c.Expr(metadata)
  }
}
```

---

### Edit 2

To apply all of the above stuff to the question of the original poster. You could use it like this

```
case class User(name: String, age: Int)
val user = User("", 0)

def meth(metadata: Metadata) = {
  println(metadata.name + "->" + metadata.value)
}

meth(user.name)
meth(user.age)
```

Note that the solution is different from what was proposed, but within the `meth` function you can do the same (a bit more even).

Comment: Hi EECOLOR. Wow! This is my first ever contact with macros. After staring blankly at this code for a while, I think I somewhat understand the idea. Except: This method "anyToMetadataImpl( )" - is it directly related to my specific problem? (in other words: what from its definition is given by my class User - if anything at all?). Or maybe it's something generic, that can be used in any case? Thanks a lot for taking the time for this!

Comment: I have edited my answer, I hope you can see how it is related. You call a method and supply a property (`user.name` for example), because it's typed as `Metadata` it triggers the macro. Instead of the name of the user, you will get the `Metadata` that allows you to request the content of that property at runtime.

Comment: Indeed, i see now. Also, I believe it's generic enough to be reusable with other classes, since I don't see any direct reference to the class User. Great! Still, I think it's a bit of an overkill to actually use it in my trivial case - just too much for too little. I'll go ahead and accept your answer, since it's an actual solution to my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for is Scala's "structural type" (not really a Scala innovation).

It captures non-nominal typing but its implementation on the JVM necessitates the use of reflection at the point in your code where you want to actually access or invoke the members dictated by the structural type. Hence there's a pretty non-trivial overhead associated with using structural types in Scala. (I recall hearing talk about implementing some kind of cache for the required reflection-derived information, but I don't know if that was ever implemented).