# Scala SQL DSL (Internal/External)

Tags: sql, scala, dsl

I have been looking into scala primarily on how to build DSL similar to C# LINQ/SQL. Having worked with C# LINQ Query provider, it was easy to introduce our own custom query provider which translated LINQ query to our own proprietary data store scripts. I am looking something similar in scala for eg.

```
 val query = select Min(Close), Max(Close)
 from   StockPrices 
 where  open > 0
```

First of all is this even possible to achieve in scala using internal DSL.

Any thoughts/ideas in this regard is highly appreciated.

I am still new in scala space, but started looking into Scala MetaProgramming & Slick. My complaint with Slick is i want to align my DSL close to SQL query - similar to above syntax.

Comment: How does the generated SQL look like? And what does `Open,Close` and `Open.Close` mean? Is `open` a property of `StockPrices`?

Comment: sorry, it was a typo, i have fixed my original post. i will translate this query into our proprietary scripting language. However, i got the idea based on your code example and started reading about macro, lets see how far I go from here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to have an internal DSL (with the currently release) that looks exactly like the example you provided.

Using a macro I still had from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14959561/function-type-of-all-methods-of-a-single-class-in-scala), the closest I could get (relatively fast) was:

```
select(Min(StockPrices.Open), Max(StockPrices.Open))
  .from(StockPrices)
```

A `real` solution would take quite some time to create. If you are willing to do that you could come quite far using macro's (not a simple topic).

If you really want the exact same syntax I recommend something like [XText](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/) that allows you to create a DSL with an eclipse based editor for 'free'.

The code required for the above example (I did not include the mentioned macro):

```
trait SqlElement {
  def toString(): String
}

trait SqlMethod extends SqlElement {
  protected val methodName: String
  protected val arguments: Seq[String]

  override def toString() = {
    val argumentsString = arguments mkString ","
    s"$methodName($argumentsString)"
  }
}

case class Select(elements: Seq[SqlElement]) extends SqlElement {
  override def toString() = s"SELECT ${elements mkString ", "}"
}

case class From(table: Metadata) extends SqlElement {
  private val tableName = table.name
  override def toString() = s"FROM $tableName"
}
case class Min(element: Metadata) extends SqlMethod {
  val methodName = "Min"
  val arguments = Seq(element.name)
}
case class Max(element: Metadata) extends SqlMethod {
  val methodName = "Max"
  val arguments = Seq(element.name)
}

class QueryBuilder(elements: Seq[SqlElement]) {
  def this(element: SqlElement) = this(Seq(element))

  def from(o: Metadata) = new QueryBuilder(elements :+ From(o))
  def where(element: SqlElement) = new QueryBuilder(elements :+ element)
  override def toString() = elements mkString ("\n")
}

def select(args: SqlElement*) = new QueryBuilder(Select(args))

trait Column
object Column extends Column

object tables {

  object StockPrices$ {
    val Open: Column = Column
    val Close: Column = Column
  }
  val StockPrices = StockPrices$
}
```

And then to use it:

```
import tables._
import StockPrices._

select(Min(StockPrices.Open), Max(StockPrices.Open))
  .from(StockPrices)
  .toString
```

Comment: Would be interesting seeing the macro as well. We want to evolve into such a direction with [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org) in 2014...

Comment: The question to which I answered with the macro is linked in the answer, here is the direct link to the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14968212/596816

Answer (score 1):

That is an admirable project, but one that has been embarked upon and which is available in general release.

I'm talking about [Slick](http://slick.typesafe.com/), of course.

Answer (score 1):

If Scala / Java interoperability is not too much of an issue for you, and if you're willing to use an internal DSL with a couple of syntax quirks compared to the syntax you have suggested, then [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org) is growing to be a popular alternative to [Slick](http://slick.typesafe.com/). An example from the [jOOQ manual](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/getting-started/jooq-and-scala/):

```
for (r <- e
    select (
      T_BOOK.ID * T_BOOK.AUTHOR_ID,
      T_BOOK.ID + T_BOOK.AUTHOR_ID * 3 + 4,
      T_BOOK.TITLE || " abc" || " xy"
    )
    from T_BOOK
    leftOuterJoin (
      select (x.ID, x.YEAR_OF_BIRTH)
      from x
      limit 1
      asTable x.getName()
    )
    on T_BOOK.AUTHOR_ID === x.ID
    where (T_BOOK.ID <> 2)
    or (T_BOOK.TITLE in ("O Alquimista", "Brida"))
    fetch
) {
  println(r)
}
```